# Dynamic scope in Autoform pushArray (attach reply into specified commentId)

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-autoform

I have `singlePost` with `postId`. In each `singlePost`, I list comment.

Autoform for comment:

```
  {{#autoForm id="updateCommentArray" type="update-pushArray" collection=Collections.Posts doc=commentDoc scope="comment" template="semanticUI"}}
    {{> afQuickField name="content"}}
    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" class="ui positive button">Submit</button>
      <button type="reset" class="ui negative button">Reset</button>
    </div>
  {{/autoForm}}
```

What Autoform provide is to use scope to attach new array into specified field. For example, when I use scope `comment.0.reply`, that reply will attach to first array of comment. When I use scope `comment.1.reply`, that reply will attach to second array of comment. Etc

How to make it dynamic? What I thought is to use `commentId`, but how?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think it works like this:

The **scope** defines to which array inside a document the form is adding.
The **doc** is the document where the form shall add data to the scope.

For example (i did not test this, but it is similar to code i used):

**javascript:**

```
CommentsSchema = new SimpleSchema({
    comment:{
        type:String,
        autoform:{
            rows: 2
        }
    }
});
PostSchema = new SimpleSchema ({
    content:{
        type:String,
        autoform: {
            rows: 2
        }
    },
    comments:{
        type:[CommentsSchema]
    }
});
```

**template:**

```
{{#each posts}}
    {{#autoForm id=this._id type="update-pushArray" collection='Posts' doc=this scope="comment" template="semanticUI"}}
    {{> afQuickField name="content"}}
    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" class="ui positive button">Submit</button>
      <button type="reset" class="ui negative button">Reset</button>
    </div>
  {{/autoForm}}
{{/each}}
```